# Append section data in ajax add to cart

Tags: magento2.3, ajaxaddtocart, customer-data, section

How we can add our own section data after ajax add to cart and use it display in pupup.

I want to add my data here in the response.
https://prnt.sc/q9v5tq

and when add to cart done i want to show it in popup.

in `checkout/cart/add` response is `null`.

`minicart` and other section used data from section load.

Answer (score 0):

app/etc/frontend/sections.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
   <action name="ajaxcart/cart/showPopup">
      <section name="cart"/>
   </action>
</config>
```

you need to create a controller named showPopup at path Controller/Cart/showPopup.php

```
namespace Extrembler\Ajaxcart\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

class ShowPopup extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart,
            $productRepository
        );
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $htmlPopup = 'I am from section of extrembler';
        $result['html_popup'] = $htmlPopup;

        return $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: only this code will enough for this?

Comment: can you please post full answer please

Comment: @MageLerner you need to create a controller named showPopup at path Controller/Cart/showPopup.php

Comment: @MageLerner Check updated full answer.

Comment: How will my action run.I have added this code but not working

Comment: @MageLerner check this module. Download and use this code as reference. 
https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/